# My classes in project randomly become invisible to other classes in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ editor, I am facing this trouble that randomly some files becomes invisible to other files using them.

I have tried refreshing the workspace and even rebuilding the project but error won't go away even though the build never complains, the problem would suddenly disappear for a file and reappear for others.

[image: My editors screenshot with one such incident.]

When class is available it should not give red squiggly lines in the editor as it hampers in other code editing tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this problem it's simple
goto File | then select invalidate cache and restart option, it resolved the issue, answering.